# Sort Class List by specific Variable

Tags: c#, .net, linq, sorting

I have a list of classes, which contains a string. The string I want to use to order the list by, looks like this: `"A1534-11"`

I would like to order them by the 4 numbers after the letter. The basic `OrderBy` method just sorts it by the letter. How can I do that?

This is what I would like to have:

```
"A1534-11"
"D1535-11"
"C1536-11"
```

Comment: 1. Learn how to extract that portion of the string 2. Use that in the `OrderBy`

Comment: I would suggest you look into the IComparer interface. It is more work but for later it's easier to read.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use LINQ and [`TakeWhile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534804(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
var result = lst.OrderBy(c => int.Parse(string.Join("",c.Name.Skip(1)
                             .TakeWhile(char.IsDigit)))).ToList();
```

I assumed that your class has a property with name `Name`. Of course you should change it to your property's name.

Comment: I like this, because it has built-in flexibility for the number of digits.

Answer (score 6):

You can parse that substring and use the result integer for the LINQ method `OrderBy`:

```
list = list.OrderBy(x => int.Parse(x.Text.Substring(1, 4))).ToList();
```